# Initialized enum returns wrong hashValue

Tags: ios, swift, enums

This is Swift 1.2 and I'm using Xcode 6.4. The following enum has a failable initializer.

```
enum EstimateItemStatus: Int, Printable {
    case Pending = 1
    case OnHold = 2
    case Done = 3

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .Pending: return "Pending"
        case .OnHold: return "On Hold"
        case .Done: return "Done"
        }
    }

    init?(id : Int) {
        switch id {
        case 1:
            self = .Pending
        case 2:
            self = .OnHold
        case 3:
            self = .Done
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

If I pass an ID and initialize an instance, the enum value I get is correct. However the `hashValue` is wrong. For example,

```
let status = EstimateItemStatus(id: 2)!
println("\(status.hashValue) - \(status)")
```

The output I get is **1 - On Hold**.

But it should be 2 - On Hold.

What am I doing wrong here? Is this a compiler bug or am I missing something?

[Demo playground](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vy7tydb5thizvnc/AAB1T7kCiY1VrOznuS13a88ga?dl=0)

Comment: Does Swift not have fallthrough in its `switch` blocks?

Comment: Maybe you're mixing up `hashValue` vs. `rawValue`. The hash value is not enforced to be equal to the raw value.

Comment: @vadian You're right! If you can post this as an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you :)

Comment: @Isuru:  Btw, enumerations (without associated values) automatically have a `init?(rawValue: RawValue)` initializer, your init method is not needed.

Comment: @MartinR Oh cool. Didn't know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're mixing up `hashValue` vs. `rawValue`.
The hash value is not enforced to be equal to the raw value